# Every bipartite Eulerian graph is a Hamilton graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

This is a true/false question I'm trying to solve to prepare for my exam. Could someone confirm my answer and help me prove it?

What I think: false, but I can not come up with an example.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Consider $K_{6, 2}$; the complete graph with $6$ vertices on one side and only $2$ on the other.

Comment: Oh I take away the two points that belong to the side with only two points and I have six disconnected vertices left => the graph is not Hamilton?

Comment: and can I also conclude that every bipartite Eulerian graph has an even amount of edges?

Comment: Or just $K_{4,2}$

Comment: @Ricardi Conclude from what?? It's true that every bipartite Eulerian graph has an even number of edges, but that fact seems unrelated to the question you asked here.

Comment: @bof, it was more of a side-note that I made. Conclude from the fact that we have a bipartite Eulerian graph, so we have an even amount of even degrees in each cycle, and using the handshake principle we know that the number of edges will also be even? those are just things I'm trying to prove to prepare myself, even though it is like you said not really related to the question